# Authentication issue with Gmail using the Socialite package in Laravel 6 and Angular?

Tags: angular, laravel, jwt, angular-routing, laravel-socialite

I am implementing `authentication` using `Laravel` and `Angular` with `JWT`. There is a `login` button that works well, and I have set up an `Angular routing` system`that redirects to the`login page`if the user is not authenticated. Here is the`routing system`:

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  {path:"", component:LandingPageComponent            }, 
  { path:"annonces",  children:[ 
    { path:"", component:IndexAnnonceComponent              },
    { path:"show/:slug", component:ShowAnnonceComponent  },
    { path:"add", component:AddAnnonceComponent          },
    { path:"edit/:slug", component:EditAnnonceComponent  }, 
    { path:"profil", component:ShowUserComponent  }, 
    { path:"chat", component:ChatComponent  }, 
    { path:"cart", component:CartComponent  }, 
    ], canActivate:[AuthGuard]
  },

  { path:"tinghirs",  children:[
    { path:"", component:IndexTinghirComponent                  },
    { path:"show/:slug", component:ShowTinghirComponent    },
    { path:"add", component:AddTinghirComponent             },
    { path:"edit/:slug", component:EditTinghirComponent     }, 
    ]
  },

  { path:"login",component:LoginComponent,canActivate:[AfterAuthGuard] },
  { path:"register",component:RegisterComponent                        },
  { path: "**", component:PageNotFoundComponent                        } 
];
```

I have added a `"Sign in with Google"` button, and I have configured `Laravel` and `Angular`, and it works fine `socialite package`. However, my problem is that when I click on the `"Sign in with Google"` button, it opens the `Gmail site`, I choose the Gmail account I want to authenticate with, but then it redirects to the `login page`. How can I resolve this issue?